# MongoDB: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, locale

I got this error message when trying to start `mongod`:

```
Tue Oct 29 21:33:23.589 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid, terminating
```

I have tried remove it and re-installing, but I got the same error.

What can I do?

Comment: Start the server, maybe? Run `mongod` command.

Comment: I start it using mongod and the same error still

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The error message:
`locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid` indicates that `mongod` is unable to work with your operating system's current [locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale).

Adjusting your locale to [`C`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do), which is supported by Mongo, will fix the problem:

```
export LC_ALL=C
mongod
```

This isn't a perfect solution, however: `LC_ALL=C` forces sorted by byte order rather than locale-sensitive character ordering,

MongoDB locale support is generally lacking. There is an [open JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1920) discussing locale support.

Comment: it return this error   ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo

Comment: I ran -dbpath ~/db and it return  ERROR: dbpath (/root/db) does not exist. Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.

Comment: and when I run /etc/init.d/mongod start it rerun bash: /etc/init.d/mongod: No such file or directory

Comment: sorry again, I run mongod --fork --dbpath ~/db --logpath ~/mongodb.log --logappend    and return ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14 and mongod not started yet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40235/discussion-between-jetawe-and-joews)

Comment: Great! Settting the LC_ALL to C solved my problem =). What did that do?

Comment: It sets your OS locale to a setting that `mongod` understands. See here for more detail: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Comment: I just got the same error, and fixed it following this solution. Funny thing? It used to work, and I did no changes to my system. So there's that...