# throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what(): locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Tags: c++, locale

I executed the following command (a tool that I need) and got:

```
$ $TOOLS/moses/moses_20150318/bin/kbmira
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted
```

I followed [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100708/mongodb-mongorestore-failure-localefacet-s-create-c-locale-name-not-valid/32762296#32762296) on how to solve it, and since I am not a root I added this line to my ~/.bashrc but no changes.

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

`$locale -a` gives

```
en_US
en_US.ISO-8859-1
en_US.UTF-8
en_ZA
```

and many other entries. I also looked if "locale" was included somewhere in the source files but could not find anything.

```
-bash-4.2$ grep  "locale" $DIR/mert/*.cpp
-bash-4.2$ grep  "locale" $DIR/mert/*.h
```

Any ideas on what's causing this.

Thanks.

Comment: stackoverflow.com isn't, unfortunately, the Psychic Friends Network. At a bare minimum, a [mcve] is required.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How about a "to-the-point", helpful comment instead. I am a beginner with c++ and trying to understand the core of the error, if there is anything "Psychic Friends Network" related in my post, how about you point it out.

Comment: How do you expect someone to figure out the problem with some C++ code, why it's throwing an exception, if you don't even show the code? Did you read the help center's article on a [mcve], that I helpfully provided, before replying? If not, why not?

Comment: The code is not mine, and the package contains more than 60 files (.h and .cpp). The problem is not with the code (and I am not supposed to change the code), it is with me using one of the binaries downloaded. And yes, I read the help center's article.

Comment: You could try using export LC_ALL=C

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks @Schore. Could you please explain why LC_ALL=C works?

Comment: Beats me. I googled and that was what turned up. Link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668570/mongodb-localefacet-s-create-c-locale-name-not-valid

Comment: Got it, thanks @Schore!

Answer (score 0):

## BITCOIN Container

- If you are getting this error, just setup the env var `LC_ALL: C` in case locale has been setup in the host.